# FileStream.BeginRead doesn't seem to return to callback

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I'm using Async to read usb device with c#. I'm using filestream to do this. when I do a FileStream.BeginRead. it doesn't seem to do the callback. what can be this problem?

this i my code

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Initialises the device
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strPath">Path to the device</param>
    private void Initialise(String strPath)
    {
        // Create the file from the device path
        SafeHandle = CreateFile(strPath, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 
            EFileAttributes.Overlapped, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (SafeHandle != null) // if the open worked...
        {
            IntPtr lpData;
            if (HidD_GetPreparsedData(SafeHandle, out lpData))
                // get windows to read the device data into an internal buffer
            {
                try
                {
                    HidCaps hidCaps;
                    HidP_GetCaps(lpData, out hidCaps); // extract the device capabilities from the internal buffer
                    InputReportLength = hidCaps.InputReportByteLength; // get the input...
                    OutputReportLength = hidCaps.OutputReportByteLength; // ... and output report lengths
                    FileStream = new FileStream((SafeFileHandle) SafeHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, InputReportLength,
                                                true); // wrap the file handle in a .Net file stream
                    BeginAsyncRead(); // kick off the first asynchronous read
                }
                finally
                {
                    HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref lpData);
                        // before we quit the function, we must free the internal buffer reserved in GetPreparsedData
                }
            }
            else // GetPreparsedData failed? Chuck an exception
                throw HidDeviceException.GenerateWithWinError("GetPreparsedData failed");
        }
        else    // File open failed? Chuck an exception
        {
            SafeHandle = null;
            throw HidDeviceException.GenerateWithWinError("Failed to create device file");
        }
    }
```

this is the callback

```
       /// <summary>
    /// Kicks off an asynchronous read which completes when data is read or when the device
    /// is disconnected. Uses a callback.
    /// </summary>
    private void BeginAsyncRead()
    {
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[InputReportLength];
        // put the buff we used to receive the stuff as the async state then we can get at it when the read completes
        FileStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, InputReportLength, ReadCompleted, buffer);
    }
```

this is my callback

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Callback for above. Care with this as it will be called on the background thread from the async read
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iResult">Async result parameter</param>
    private void ReadCompleted(IAsyncResult iResult)
    {
        Byte[] buffer = (Byte[])iResult.AsyncState; // retrieve the read buffer
        try
        {
            FileStream.EndRead(iResult);    // call end read : this throws any exceptions that happened during the read
            try
            {
                HandleDataReceived(buffer); // pass the new input report on to the higher level handler
            }
            finally
            {
                BeginAsyncRead();   // when all that is done, kick off another read for the next report
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) // if we got an IO exception, the device was removed
        {
            HandleDeviceRemoved();
            if (OnDeviceRemoved != null)
                OnDeviceRemoved(this, new EventArgs());
            Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE** i was wondering if I'm doing wrong here in the devicePath

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to return the device path given a DeviceInterfaceData structure and an InfoSet handle.
    /// Used in 'FindDevice' so check that method out to see how to get an InfoSet handle and a DeviceInterfaceData.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hInfoSet">Handle to the InfoSet</param>
    /// <param name="oInterface">DeviceInterfaceData structure</param>
    /// <returns>The device path or null if there was some problem</returns>
    private static string GetDevicePath(IntPtr hInfoSet, ref DeviceInterfaceData oInterface)
    {
        uint nRequiredSize = 0;
        // Get the device interface details
        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hInfoSet, ref oInterface, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref nRequiredSize, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            DeviceInterfaceDetailData oDetail = new DeviceInterfaceDetailData();

            oDetail.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 4 ? 8 : 5; // check if is a 64 bit

            if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hInfoSet, ref oInterface, ref oDetail, nRequiredSize, ref nRequiredSize, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                return oDetail.DevicePath;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: show your code..Then others can help you .

Comment: Where is ReadCompleted? That's really the key function. Also, don't send your buffer as the final argument, send the stream because you need to close it (it's not nice to leave files open indefinitely). Really we need to see BeginAsyncRead and ReadCompleted side by side.

Comment: @DanielKelley i just the a copy past of my code

Comment: Looks good so far, if you put a break point in BeginAsyncRead and ReadCompleted, do you hit both of them?

Comment: @sircodesalot: it only hids BeginAsyncRead never ReadComplete

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the callback as a parameter into the method call, like in this example:

```
public void LoadFile(string fileName)
{  
    currentFileStream = new FileStream("Foo.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024 * 8, true);
    buffer = new byte[currentFileStream.Length];
    currentFileStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, FileReadComplete, currentFileStream);
}

private void FileReadComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // do your code
}
```

Comment: So in writing up the example for this, I came across something. The IAsyncResult.AsyncState doesn't can only hold one item. So how would you get th filestream (in order to close it) and the buffer (in order to capture the stored data) to the callback without creating another structure? In my example I just make it global-ish, but I think that sucks.

Comment: @sircodesalot Just use a closure to capture all of the variables that you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a synchronization object that gets  
// signaled when verification is complete.
ManualResetEvent manualEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// Create random data to write to the file. 
byte[] writeArray = new byte[100000];
new Random().NextBytes(writeArray);

FileStream fStream = 
    new FileStream("Test#@@#.dat", FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 4096, true);

// Check that the FileStream was opened asynchronously.
Console.WriteLine("fStream was {0}opened asynchronously.",
    fStream.IsAsync ? "" : "not ");

// Asynchronously write to the file.
IAsyncResult asyncResult = fStream.BeginWrite(
    writeArray, 0, writeArray.Length, 
    new AsyncCallback(EndWriteCallback), 
    new State(fStream, writeArray, manualEvent));

// Concurrently do other work and then wait  
// for the data to be written and verified.
manualEvent.WaitOne(5000, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can take a look at a quick sample I wrote up.

```
class Program
{
    static Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

    public static void Main()
    {
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("data.txt");
        fileStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(FileReadCallback), fileStream);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void FileReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = (FileStream)result.AsyncState;
        fileStream.EndRead(result);

        foreach (Byte b in buffer)
            Console.Write((Char)b);

    }
}
```

Although this method works, it's very old-c++ style. It's much easier just to write something like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("data.txt"))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            // This will read a single line of text
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

And just execute it on another thread using the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class, as in:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(ThisWillExecuteOnAnotherThread);
    }

    public static void ThisWillExecuteOnAnotherThread()
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("data.txt"))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            // This will read a single line of text
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I think this style is much much cleaner personally.

**UPDATE**

So this setup works fine on my machine:

```
class Program
{
    static byte[] buffer;
    static int InputReportLength = 1024;
    static FileStream fileStream;
    public static void Main()
    {
        BeginAsyncRead();
    }

    private static void BeginAsyncRead()
    {
        buffer = new Byte[InputReportLength];
        fileStream = File.OpenRead("Data.txt");

        // put the buff we used to receive the stuff as the async state then we can get at it when the read completes
        fileStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, InputReportLength, ReadCompleted, buffer);
    }

    private static void ReadCompleted(IAsyncResult iResult)
    {
        Byte[] buffer = (Byte[])iResult.AsyncState; // retrieve the read buffer

    }

}
```

I would reccomend that you not do this:

```
FileStream FileStream = ....
```

Generally you should 'PascalCase' your class names and 'camelCase' your variables. Also, as a general reccomentation, the way your code is structured requires you to make a number of jumps on the page, which will make it difficult for you to maintain should you ever need to look at your code again later. Try to keep things as close together as possible.

Comment: You want to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` rather than `new Task`.  Partly because you need to call `Start()` for it to actually start, and because constructing a task like that should only be done if you don't intend to start it right away.

Comment: @sircodesalot As I said, you shouldn't be using the `Task` constructor, you should be using `Run` or `StartNew`.

Comment: Oh, nm I get it now. Thank you sir. Do you know if there are similar semantics for System.Threading.Thread?